# Input value substitution not working for message cards in MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, office365connectors

I'm doing a HttpPost from a message card with some user input fields. The message card is sent to MS teams and contains a Http Post action to another target which receives the user's selected inputs. I'm sending User's data in body of the Http Post. Input value substitution works fine in MS teams desktop but not working in MS teams android. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Snippet with httpPost:

```
    {
      "@type": "ActionCard",
      "actions": [
        {
          "@type": "HttpPOST",
          "body": "{\"Comment\":\"{{Comment.value}}\",\"Choice1\" : \"{{1c.value}}\",\"Choice2\" : \"{{2c.value}}\"}",

          "name": "Submit Edit",
          "target": "https://.."
        }
      ],
      "inputs": [
        {
          "@type": "TextInput",
          "id": "Comment",
          "isMultiline": true,
          "isRequired": true,
          "title": "Comment"
        },
        {
          "@type": "TextInput",
          "id": "1c",
          "title": "Choice 1"
        },
        {
          "@type": "TextInput",
          "id": "2c",
          "title": "Choice 2"
        }
      ],
      "name": "Edit"
    }
  ]
}
```

Body received from MS teams android:

```
"body": {
    "Comment": "{{Comment.value}}",
    "Choice1": "{{1c.value}}",
    "Choice2": "{{2c.value}}"
}
```

Body received from MS teams desktop:

```
"body": {
    "Comment": "Test",
    "Choice1": "Myinput",
    "Choice2": "Myinput"
}
```

Comment: I tested this my side and got the same result, even bodyContentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" to double check. It seems that these actions are not supported properly on mobile, but perhaps someone else has more info

Comment: @Shishir Thanks for reporting this. We could repro it and we have raised a bug for this.

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT Thank you for the quick analysis. Please keep me posted.

Comment: @Shishir I tried the codes in this page, it doesn't work at my side. I am getting empty string for this syntax {{<id of input>.value}}. Is there anything changed ever since, does your code still work?